# Maven tapestry-tldgen plugin: Failed to execute goal because of tools.jar dependency

Tags: maven-3, tapestry

I'm having a bit of an issue with a Maven plugin.  I'm trying to run the [tapestry-tldgen](http://exanpe.free.fr/tapestry-tldgen/usage.html) plugin.  I am getting the following error and can't get myself past the issue.

```
Failed to execute goal fr.exanpe:tapestry-tldgen:1.1.0:tld-generate
(default) on project maple: Execution default of goal 
fr.exanpe:tapestry-tldgen:1.1.0:tld-generate failed: Plugin
fr.exanpe:tapestry-tldgen:1.1.0 or one of its dependencies could
not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 
at specified path /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/../lib/tools.jar
```

I think my resolution is related to performing an exclusion.  But, I cannot find a good example of how to exclude a dependency from a plugin.  I am using OS X.  I'm hoping someone can point me to a good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can answer my own question.  Instead of excluding, I changed the location of the tools dependency.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>fr.exanpe</groupId>
  <artifactId>tapestry-tldgen</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

...

</plugin>
```